# Issue with copying from one MySQL table to another

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to copy from one table to another table and it works fine, however I also need to insert the current user ID in the new table. I haven't yet figured out how. Normally I would do something like `SET user_id = :user_id`, but i have never worked with this one.

This is my code:

```
$q = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO user_themes(title,code_entry,code_home,code_css,code_category,code_archive)
    SELECT title, code_entry, code_home, code_css, code_category, code_archive FROM blogy_themes WHERE id = :id");
```

**So my question is:** 
How can I insert `user_id` (let's say user_id is 1) into the new table as well?

Comment: Add a column and insert it - haven't you tried that?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I have added the column (user_id) in the database, but can't figure out how to implement it in the query..

Comment: Just add new column user_id and insert it . Note- dont set auto-increment to that field.

Comment: Is this PDO? If so, execute with the ID required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basis of your query doesn't change. Just add the value to both the columns and `SELECT statement:

```
INSERT INTO user_themes(user_id, title,code_entry,code_home,code_css,code_category,code_archive)
  SELECT :user_id, title, code_entry, code_home, code_css, code_category, code_archive
    FROM blogy_themes WHERE id = :id
```

Then when you execute, bind both `:id` and `:user_id`.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to have the id of the user that is doing the action in all of the new records, you can do something like:

```
$q = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO user_themes(user_id,title,code_entry,code_home,code_css,code_category,code_archive)
SELECT '" . (int) $userid ."' as user_id, title, code_entry, code_home, code_css, code_category, code_archive FROM blogy_themes WHERE id = :id");
```

This is a workaround in order to keep using the query as it is. 
Second option is more "ORM" approach, you can query all the relevant records from the user_themes table, iterate on the result set, clone each row and save it with new user_id.

Comment: Yes exactly. It worked, but had to remove "as" though and replace it with comma.

Comment: Why did you take something that has placeholders and then go and wreck it?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks for your concerns, but I don't accept before I know it's working correctly and I bet there are other solutions that aren't workarounds.

Comment: *"Yes exactly. It worked, but had to remove "as" though and replace it with comma."* <= What do you call that? @kanarifugl The operative words here are "It worked". Or, what am I not grasping?

Comment: @Fred-ii- By all means, I see your point, but as mentioned it is a workaround, and the answer below seems more right after testing a bit. Therefore I haven't accepted yet - to investigate other solutions. But your'e right, I thought it was the best answer at first. Thanks for the article, anyway.

Comment: @kanarifugl the other way is the ORM approach, fetch the results and insert them with new user_id (you can do that also with native sql but you will still need to change the value of the user_id). I don't see any "magic way"